# Using .DrawToBitmap - how to change resolution of image?

Tags: c#, .net, image

Im using `DrawToBitmap` to save some labels as image. I would like to know how to change the resolution of these images, is there a way? Say I have a label with a text and I want to render it to an image file (not posting the full code):

```
this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
this.label1.AutoSize = true;
this.label1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Baskerville Old Face", 36F);
//...
this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(161, 54);
this.label1.Text = "Output";
//...

//save image:
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(161, 54);
this.label1.DrawToBitmap(image, this.label1.ClientRectangle);
image.Save(@"C:\image.jpg");
```

This is working fine, I will get something like this:

[image: Resultant image]

The resolution is ok, but is it possible to increase it? When I zoom into this image a little, I can see the individual pixels as large blocks:

[image: Zoomed resultant image]

I know that's normal, because its not a vector graphic and that's fine. I just would like to change it somehow, so that you can zoom in further before seeing individual pixels as large blocks. Any ideas?

Thank you.

Edit: If Im using only black/white images - is it maybe better to save the image as png or gif?

Comment: I have edited the wording of the question to be more clear.

Comment: No, this feature is only available in the Law & Order crime labs.  In real life you have to give the label a bigger Font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will do the job, just increase font size used from label:

```
    Bitmap CreateBitmapImage(string text, Font textFont, SolidBrush textBrush)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(1, 1);
        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
        int intWidth = (int)graphics.MeasureString(text, textFont).Width;
        int intHeight = (int)graphics.MeasureString(text, textFont).Height;
        bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmap, new Size(intWidth, intHeight));
        graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
        graphics.Clear(Color.White);
        graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
        graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        graphics.DrawString(text, textFont, textBrush,0,0);
        graphics.Flush();
        return (bitmap);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this is good - the problem is: I would like to keep using a label and lable.DrawToBitmap. Or is it not possible?

Comment: DrawToBitmap uses graphics from Label, so you always end up with text resolution defined by Label size. You can size up Rectangle passed to DrawToBitmap but it will not zoom the text. I guess only option is to use something like "CreateBitmapImage" to make quality text zoom.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by increasing the value of second parameter of System.Drawing.Font.

```
this.label1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Baskerville Old Face", 1000F);
```

Comment: Thats what I thought first. The problem now: I have to increase my image size, so this font can fit in it. Is there a way to keep the x,y size of a picture the same but put a much larger font in it?