# VB6 vs VB2017 print a form

Tags: printform

I have developed a program for windows with visual basic 6 for printing orders in a pizzeria, I display a window and print it with "me.printform". Now I'm redoing it in vb.net, but the print quality is bad. I've read several solutions but it doesn't change. Anyone know how "printform" works in vb6 ?

I tried to save the image in a bitmap, print directly, but nothing to do, probably in vb6 the FORM.PRINTFORM method has some setting that I don't know...

Comment: Please show the VB code, because I do not know why you need an image for printing a form

Comment: Or maybe even add a picture of an order for a "pizza Hawaï" ?

Comment: BTW: Did you see the first result for: [searching: printform [vb6]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=printform+%5Bvb6%5D) ?   It finds: [How to increase print quality with PrintForm in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870107/how-to-increase-print-quality-with-printform-in-c-sharp), which is not a (direct) answer to your question, but show that you need to provide more info to this problem. (Please show the VB6 code, as a [mre])

Comment: now I look, I know the problem is the resolution difference between screen and printer, in vb6 I didn't have this problem

Comment: OK, now you will have to find out where this problem is coming from, because resolution of picture showed on screen is not changed  (by itself)  since VB6. (AFAIK)

Comment: in vb6 the command line is : "me.prinform"
the form is composed of a series of labels with the data to be printed, simply.

Comment: in vb.net: Me.DrawToBitmap(bmp, New Rectangle(fromLeft, fromTop, mWidth, mHeight)) an i use printdocument..

Comment: [Using .DrawToBitmap - how to change resolution of image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13193212/using-drawtobitmap-how-to-change-resolution-of-image)  ??

Comment: Exactly! Same pc, same printer...probably there's some setting, you should exactly replicate vb6's Printform method

Comment: I tried changing image resolution, printer resolution, size of the area to be printed....nothing

Comment: the print quality does not always change the same and bad